# Error while adding image to imageview

Tags: android, imageview

Hi I'm really new in Fragments to so please bear with me. I'm trying to set profile pic from either gallery or camera. The code is working fine with "extends Activity" but getting force closed in Fragment.

```js
Error Logcat output

12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687): Process: com.example.areal, PID: 9687
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131074, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/32375 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.areal/com.example.areal.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3591)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3634)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:155)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-14 10:14:11.112: E/AndroidRuntime(9687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
```

```css
Manifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.areal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```html
Class Fragment

public class Profile extends Fragment{
 
 ImageView viewImage;
 Context context;
 
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
  
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.profile, null);
  
  viewImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  viewImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selectImage();
   }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Profile.this.getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    

                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

  });
  
  
  
  
  
  return v;
  
 }
 

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        //requestCode=0 for Camera
        if (requestCode == 0 && responseCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if (bitmap != null) {
               //Process with bitmap
              File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                 for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                     if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                         f = temp;
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 try {
                     BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                             bitmapOptions);

                     viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                     String path = android.os.Environment
                             .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                             + File.separator
                             + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                     f.delete();
                     OutputStream outFile = null;
                     File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                     try {
                         outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                         outFile.flush();
                         outFile.close();
                     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        //requestCode=1 for Gallery
        } else if (requestCode == 1 && responseCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //NewNewsFragment.fileURI = path;
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            if (bitmap != null) {
            //Process with bitmap
             
             viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
            }
        }

    }







}
```

Comment: debug find at which line you are getting NPE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Read permission also for external storage.

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now for onActivityResult to get the bitmap from gallery and camera.You need to put onActivityResult in Activity Class and for startActivity, you need to call with that Activity reference like.

```html
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                activity.startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
```

```html
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
        //requestCode=0 for Camera
        if (requestCode == 0 && responseCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            if (bitmap != null) {
               //Process with bitmap
               
            }
        //requestCode=1 for Gallery
        } else if (requestCode == 1 && responseCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //NewNewsFragment.fileURI = path;
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            if (bitmap != null) {
            //Process with bitmap
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried but its still not working. Besides the code is working in Activity so why not in Fragment?

Comment: Check the updated answer for fragment, code is same but you need to put in Activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97811/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-arth-tilva).